# xcode crashing when missing ( on function return param

Tags: xcode

I've just finished debugging a particularly painful problem where xcode would hang/crash during a compile, and then later when I opened a particular file (once I identified which file)
At one point, it was generating 55k+ errors.

```
@interface someviewcontroller: UITableViewController {
    someeditviewcontroller *editView;
    -(classObjectName*) addRecord;
    -void)remove(classObjectName*)record;
}
```

^^^ missing the ( before the void on the remove

THis is not so much a question, but I'm curious as to why this caused a complete meltdown of both IDE and compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that was your only problem. I added the above interface declaration to a file and it didn't cause any problems at all, even though it's a bit of a nonsense header; your syntax and method/variable names are all fudged up. Here's how that interface should look.

```
@interface SomeViewController : UITableViewController {
    SomeEditViewController *editView;
}

- (classObjectName *) addRecord;
- (void)removeRecord:(classObjectName *)record;

@end
```

If I had to guess, I'd say the missing `@end` is the cause of your issues. I don't see why it would cause crashes, but it will generate a ton of errors.